# How to specify a member function (inside class is better) by the argument of class template?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have some class like

```
enum Type {ONE, TWO};

template <enum Type T>
class A {
    void foo() {}
};
```

I want to specify the function `foo()` according to the template argument `T` of the class. Is it possible to be done inside the class ? Or, how to do it outside the class?

**Edit:**

what if my class is

```
template <class U, enum Type T>
class A {
    void foo() {}
};
```

This class cannot be simply specialized by giving two version of `foo`
I found a solution at [What is wrong with partial template specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128535/what-is-wrong-with-partial-template-specialization)
which may turn out to make the code very long.

Is there any other solution to this, or should some other design be used ?

Comment: Templates are the wrong tools for this - inheritance perchance

Comment: @EdHeal class `A` also needs to be inherited, so I don't want to make two classes only for this one function.

Comment: @EdHeal: In what sense are templates "the wrong tools for this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specialize members functions of class templates. You simply do:

```
template <>
void A<ONE>::foo()
{
//ONE stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you can use tag-dispatching. In this particular instance, they don't make much sense, but they might if your requirements are slightly different.

```
template <enum Type T>
class A
{
public:
  void foo() {fooImpl(std::conditional_t<T==ONE, std::true_type, std::false_type>());}

  void fooImpl(std::true_type)
  {
    cout << "ONE" << endl; 
  }

  void fooImpl(std::false_type)
  {
    cout << "TWO" << endl; 
  }
};
```

With the above definition,

```
int main()
{
  A<ONE>().foo();
  A<TWO>().foo();
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
ONE
TWO
```

Comment: ur solution needs to be written outside of the class. Is there any solution inside the class `A`?

Comment: @Kozuki Why would that be helpful? Why template it at all if you are going to provide the implementations for all the cases in the one template definition?

Comment: I just have lots of other template arguments and don't want to copy them for every function like this.

Comment: what's a 'in-class options'?

Comment: I meant added code showing how to provide definitions inside the class.

Comment: VS2013 is giving an error for `enable_if` version:  error C2535: member function already defined or declared

Comment: Sorry, my `enable_if` example was incorrect. Have tested the above with `clang -std=c++1y`. You need C++14 for the `conditional_t` alias. If you don't have it, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Comment: what if I have another template argument in class `A`, please read my edit.